# Building a column based scatter plot and line chart in R

Tags: r

I am trying to tackle a data visualization project that illustrates that grades gathered over multiple years are consistently low.  The first problem I have is in the curation of the data.  I have a listing of students who have taken a different number of tests (3 to 10) and their grades in 2022 and 2023 (I'll add more years later).  In general, I thought it would be something like this
[image: General Look]
I would plot each test in the year it was taken and the grade.  I would also like to have each of the grades in the background as a visual reference.

For this, I would create a xls with the following columns: StudentName, TestTitle, Year, Grade

I would then like to do a chart for each student and show how their grade changed from 2022 to 2023 (again, I'll keep adding to this with each year).  I was thinking of something like this
[image: Student].

So my first question is in creating the xls, is my design the best way of going about this, or should I do something different?

Next, I used RStudio to create the visuals, and I used the following code

```
plot(myData$Grade~myData$Year, 
     main="Title", 
     xlab="X", 
     ylab="Y", 
     pch=16, 
     col=ifelse(myData$Year == "2022", "red", "blue")
)
```

I want to limit the display to only two columns, but right now it is showing 2022, 2022.2, etc.  How do I limit that?

I started with an xls and inputted in values.  Columns where StudentName, TestTitle, Year, Grade.

Here is a data snippet CSV

```
Student,Test,Year,Grade
Jim,1,2022,82
Jim,2,2022,23
Jim,3,2022,36
Bill,1,2022,43
Bill,2,2022,43
Bill,3,2022,41
Jane,1,2022,19
Jane,2,2022,19
Jane,3,2022,33
Cliff,1,2022,47
Cliff,2,2022,31
Cliff,3,2022,50
Cliff,4,2022,48
Cliff,5,2022,40
Cliff,6,2022,42
Cliff,7,2022,67
Cliff,8,2022,10
Jim,1,2023,82
Jim,2,2023,23
Jim,3,2023,36
Bill,1,2023,43
Bill,2,2023,43
Bill,3,2023,41
Jane,1,2023,19
Jane,2,2023,19
Jane,3,2023,33
Cliff,1,2023,47
Cliff,2,2023,31
Cliff,3,2023,50
Cliff,4,2023,48
Cliff,5,2023,40
Cliff,6,2023,42
Cliff,7,2023,69
Cliff,8,2023,10
```

I wanted a two-column scatter plot, but there is a gradation of the X.

Comment: Yes, this is straightforward to do if you have a column for year, a column for score, a column for studentID and a column for the test name. You also need to know how grades are calculated from scores. If you want some actual code showing how that might be done in your own case, then please [edit] your question so that it contains a [mre]

Comment: Thanks.  I have not asked many questions here, but I hope I added what you were asking for.  If not, I'll do better

Comment: Thanks Michael, but we need some sample data too. Either share your data using the `dput` function or create a fake data set that you could apply to your own case. For more information, please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example . I'm sure we can help you if your question includes this.

Comment: My CSV paste was an epic fail, but I think ou can get the basics, I hope

Comment: OK, I've used your dataset to make the desired plot type. The values don't really change from year to year in your sample data, but that doesn't affect the code. You may need to change the ymin and ymax of the annotations to match your resl grade thresholds - I had to guess these.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ggplot` here to get the background colors as rectangular annotations:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(Year, Grade)) +
  annotate("rect", xmin = -Inf, xmax = Inf, color = "black", linewidth = 0.2,
           ymin = c(0, 50, 60, 75),
           ymax = c(50, 60, 75, 100),
           fill = c("#efffe4", "#efffff", "#feffea", "#ffe9e4")) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(aes(group = interaction(Student, Test))) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(2022, 2023), expand = c(0.5, 0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 100), expand = c(0, 0)) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 16)
```

[image]

---

**Data in reproducible formats**

```r
df <- structure(list(Student = c("Jim", "Jim", "Jim", "Bill", "Bill", 
"Bill", "Jane", "Jane", "Jane", "Cliff", "Cliff", "Cliff", "Cliff", 
"Cliff", "Cliff", "Cliff", "Cliff", "Jim", "Jim", "Jim", "Bill", 
"Bill", "Bill", "Jane", "Jane", "Jane", "Cliff", "Cliff", "Cliff", 
"Cliff", "Cliff", "Cliff", "Cliff", "Cliff"), Test = c(1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L
), Year = c(2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 
2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 
2022L, 2023L, 2023L, 2023L, 2023L, 2023L, 2023L, 2023L, 2023L, 
2023L, 2023L, 2023L, 2023L, 2023L, 2023L, 2023L, 2023L, 2023L
), Grade = c(82L, 23L, 36L, 43L, 43L, 41L, 19L, 19L, 33L, 47L, 
31L, 50L, 48L, 40L, 42L, 67L, 10L, 82L, 23L, 36L, 43L, 43L, 41L, 
19L, 19L, 33L, 47L, 31L, 50L, 48L, 40L, 42L, 69L, 10L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -34L))
```

Comment: Very nicely performed!!   Thank you very much for this and also showing my how I should have presented the data.  Learned a ton on this one!